# Java 10 desktop Application - Memory leak on Windows 7 but runs fine on Windows 10

Tags: java, memory-leaks, windows-7, java-10

We have a Java 10 desktop application that is having huge memory leaks on Windows 7. Here is the situation -

1. Running on Java 8 on Windows 7 - Works fine (memory within 1-1.5 GB)
2. Running on Java 10 on Windows 10 - Works fine (memory within 1-1.2 GB)
3. Running on Java 10 on Windows 7 - Memory keeps growing until the application stops responding. We have seen memory rising to 7-8 GB (our heap limit is set to 1.5GB though). We don't get OutOfMemory exception either.

I couldn't find anything that will help me resolve this issue. I find articles talking about how to resolve memory leaks in Java, but nothing that helps resolve this scenario.

Could someone please point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance for taking the time out.

Regards,
Prasenjit

P.S.: All Windows references above are 64-bit.

Comment: This sounds like a memory leak in the JVM. You best bet is to probably update the JVM. Or use an older version that doesn’t have this problem.

Comment: Hi Van, We can't use Java 11 yet right? Actually, in our case, Java 10 resolves some of the high resolution scaling beautifully (for 4k screens) that Java 8 fails to do. We have to use multi-resolution images in Java 8 and code a lot of scaling by hand. JOptionPane icons come up cut-off as well. Hence we wanted to move to Java 10.

Comment: We could take a decision if we were sure about the compatibility issues. But nothing in the Java supported environments list suggest so. Didn't find anyone else complaining either. Hence I was wondering if there was something specific in our application that I could look at.

Comment: @Prosu *We can't use Java 11 yet right?* .. you can, just that it's not yet GA and is in ramp-down phase with the first RC coming to be available soon. Related to compatibility, one can only comment depending on the application code in use.

Comment: You don’t even need to go up a major version, there are many patches released over the lifetime of a version.

Comment: @vandench we are on the latest of Java 10.

Comment: If you can run your application in Eclipse you could try using the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/21/10-tips-for-using-the-eclipse-memory-analyzer/).

Comment: @vandench I realized I wasn't using 10.0.2 (that is the latest available). Updating to it actually solved the problem! Couldn't imagine such a memory leak would be caused by the JVM.

Comment: @skomisa I don't know what it is exactly, but sounds like a profiler. I have run profilers but couldn't get to the root of the problem. Seems now it was being caused by the JVM memory leaks.

Comment: @Prosu the JVM is written in C++. C++ is notorious for causing huge amounts of memory leaks. It is very difficult to trigger memory leak from Java. But if Oracle screws up just a little bit, it can have disastrous effects.

Comment: @vandench Thanks, good to know. If you post your comments about version upgrade as an answer I'll accept it. Though I'm more of a SO "reader" than an active user. I'm not 100% sure how this thing is supposed to work.